# How to enable CORS in AWS API Gateway via SDK Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a service that communicates directly with AWS via sdk Java, when I'm creating a API Gateway, I don't see any option to enable CORS like I can do through AWS Console UI, is there any way to do this via sdk?

Comment: it should be under actions ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: @varnit in this documentation only show how to do it via console, I need the code to do via sdk Java :)

Comment: and you can't enable it with java sdk but you can do it via cloud formation template if you want more help let me know

Comment: Really? I can create but I can't enable CORS via sdk? so sad...

Comment: from the initial search in aws sdk i could not find a clue to enable cors or anything related to cors but i'm still searching for it

Comment: I think that maybe I can do it by creating the methods and put the headers in the resource... I will see if works in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out by creating the method manually and configuring the headers, e.g:

```
AmazonApiGateway amazonApiGateway;

private void putMethod(final RestApi restApi, final Resource resource, final HttpMethod httpMethod) throws AmazonClientException {
    PutMethodRequest putMethodRequest = new PutMethodRequest()
        .withOperationName(METHOD_OPERATION_NAME)
        .withHttpMethod(httpMethod.name())
        .withResourceId(resource.getId())
        .withRestApiId(restApi.getId())
        .withAuthorizationType("NONE");

    amazonApiGateway.putMethod(putMethodRequest);
}

private void putMethodIntegration(final RestApi restApi, final Resource resource, final HttpMethod httpMethod) throws AmazonClientException {
    PutIntegrationRequest putIntegrationRequest = new PutIntegrationRequest()
        .withRestApiId(restApi.getId())
        .withResourceId(resource.getId())
        .withHttpMethod(httpMethod.name())
        .withIntegrationHttpMethod(httpMethod.name())
        .withType(IntegrationType.HTTP);

    amazonApiGateway.putIntegration(putIntegrationRequest);
}

private void putMethodResponse(final RestApi restApi, final Resource resource, final HttpMethod httpMethod, final Map<String, Boolean> methodResponseParameters) throws AmazonClientException {
    amazonApiGateway.putMethodResponse(new PutMethodResponseRequest()
        .withRestApiId(restApi.getId())
        .withResourceId(resource.getId())
        .withHttpMethod(httpMethod.name())
        .withStatusCode("200")
        .withResponseModels(Collections.singletonMap("application/json", "Empty"))
        .withResponseParameters(methodResponseParameters));
}

private void putMethodIntegrationResponse(final RestApi restApi, final Resource resource, final HttpMethod httpMethod, final Map<String, String> parameters) throws AmazonClientException{
    final Map<String, String> dataPassThroughTemplate = new HashMap<>();
    dataPassThroughTemplate.put("application/json", "");

    amazonApiGateway.putIntegrationResponse(new PutIntegrationResponseRequest()
        .withRestApiId(restApi.getId())
        .withResourceId(resource.getId())
        .withHttpMethod(httpMethod.name())
        .withStatusCode("200")
        .withResponseParameters(parameters)
        .withResponseTemplates(dataPassThroughTemplate));
}

private Map<String, Boolean> getMethodResponseParameters() {
    final Map<String, Boolean> methodResponseParameters = new HashMap<>();
    methodResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), true);
    methodResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"), true);
    methodResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"), true);
    return methodResponseParameters;
}

private Map<String, String> getIntegrationResponseParameters() {
    final Map<String, String> integrationResponseParameters = new HashMap<>();
    integrationResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"), "'*'");
    integrationResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"), "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,x-api-key,x-amz-security-token'");
    integrationResponseParameters.put(String.format(METHOD_RESPONSE_TEMPLATE, "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"), "'GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,PATCH,OPTIONS'");
    return integrationResponseParameters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS in AWS API Gateway by following [AWS SDK guideline for CORS in Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ManageCorsUsingJava.html).

Document have explained CORS setup with example including:

- Creates a CORS configuration and sets the configuration on a bucket
- Retrieves the configuration and modifies it by adding a rule
- Adds the modified configuration to the bucket
- Deletes the configuration

Comment: This document only shows how to configure to a S3, not for a API gateway.